# How can I get the second output, so if the user puts in ten instead of the integer value, would the isdigit function work for this particular problem?

Tags: python, while-loop, coding-style

Enter an integer between 1 to 10: **11**
You did not enter a number between 1 and 10!!!
Please, try again.

Enter an integer between 1 to 10: **ten**
You did not enter an integer!!!
Please, try again.

Enter an integer between 1 to 10: **.3**
You did not enter an integer!!!
Please, try.

Enter an integer between 1 to 10: **0**
Oops, you entered zero.
Please, try again.

Enter an integer between 1 to 10: **3**
The Reciprocal of your number is 0.33333333333333333.

## here is what i have right now for the first part, its working but i cant seem to figure out the rest

try:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number between 1 to 10: "))

if num in range(1, 11):
    print(num)

else:
    print("You did not enter a number between 1 and 10!!!\nPlease, try again.")
```

except ValueError:

```
 print("You did not enter an integer between 1 to 10. Try again")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please share the code which you have tried. We can help you to with modifications and correcting errors.

Answer (score 0):

move the conversion to int into the if/else area, use a try/except to handle if they enter a string, then search from a list of strings that could be 'ten" being entered. I am sure there are more elegant solutions...

```
VariantsOfTen=['ten','Ten','tEn','TEn','tEN','teN','TEN']

num = input("Enter a number between 1 to 10: ")

try: 
    if int(num) in range(1, 11):
        print(num)
    else:
        print("You did not enter a number between 1 and 10!!!\nPlease, try again.")
except:
    if (num in VariantsOfTen):
        print('that is ten, but not really..')
    else:
        print('you entered a string, but nothing useful')
```

Comment: ever heard of the functions `upper()` and `lower()`